# Declare and assign array inside HTTP body in angular

Tags: angular

I need to pass array of string object in role instead of a string?

```
saveUser(name,password,email, role1) {
              arr:String[]=[];
        return this.http.post<any>('url',
          {
            name:name,
            password:password,
            email:email,
            arr:String[0]:role,// here  need to pass an array object with value in 0 index
          }). pipe( share(),
          catchError(this.errorHandle));
```

Comment: Could you let us know role1 param's type passed. if role1 is string u can push that string as arr.push(role1), if it's an array you can directly pass it to the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
saveUser(name,password,email, role1) {
        arr:string[]=[];
        arr.push(role1);
        return this.http.post<any>('url',
          {
            name:name,
            password:password,
            email:email,
            arr:arr,// pass like this
          }). pipe( share(),
          catchError(this.errorHandle));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       role: any =[] // Global Variable for. 

saveUser(name,password,email, role1) {
              this.role = role1;
        return this.http.post<any>('url',
          {
            name:name,
            password:password,
            email:email,
            arr:this.role 
          }). pipe( share(),
          catchError(this.errorHandle));
        }
```